# Which of the two approaches to routing a module settings page is the best practice?

Tags: routes

There seems to be two ways to link a route to a settings form for a module. I'm curious as to whether one is considered a better practice, and why.

```
_controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyController::myMethod'
```

or

```
_form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\mySettingsFormFile
```

Comment: Without knowing what is in myMethod() this would be the second one. The extra custom controller class only makes sense if you do something in myMethod() the form controller invoked by `_form` is not able to do.

Comment: Makes sense. Would you mind pasting your comment as an answer, so I can select it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what is in the controller this would be the second one. The extra custom controller class only makes sense if you do something in myMethod() the [form controller invoked by _form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21HtmlFormController.php/class/HtmlFormController/8.7.x) is not able to do.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2117411#fapi-in-route

This integrates the form in a request so that it can receive route parameters and the request itself as well as returning a response if necessary.